# Android Layout Spoiler

Tags: android, user-interface

Is there a way to hide a specific part of the UI in Android by a spoiler and get it visible by clicking a button or something like this, it would be perfect if that could be implemented in a Fragment!

Thanks in advance,

forumfresser

Comment: What do you mean by a spoiler? Just a view that covers that UI element?

Comment: Yeah, actually something like that (the view must be hideable)